# Can a data frame be made to accept alists as rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, names

Consider

```
items<-alist(2^1,2^2,2^3,2^3)
```

Suppose that I want to construct a data frame where the unevaluated expressions in `items` are one column and their evaluated versions are in another. In other words, I want something like:

```
items           results
2^1                   1
2^2                   4
2^3                   8
2^3                   8
```

as my outputs. I would use the `row.names` argument, but it rejects duplicated names and cannot be convinced otherwise.

The natural thing to try is

```
items<-alist(2^1,2^2,2^3,2^3)
outs<-sapply(items,eval)
data.frame(items=items,results=outs)
```

but the outputs appears to treat each element of the `alist` as if it were a column name:

```
> data.frame(items=items,results=outs)
  items.2.1 items.2.2 items.2.3 items.2.3.1 results
1         2         4         8           8       2
2         2         4         8           8       4
3         2         4         8           8       8
4         2         4         8           8       8
```

`lapply` does not fair any better:

```
> outs<-lapply(items,eval)
> data.frame(items=items,results=outs)
  items.2.1 items.2.2 items.2.3 items.2.3.1 results.2 results.4 results.8 results.8.1
1         2         4         8           8         2         4         8           8
```

I am aware that I could use a matrix instead of a data frame, but that is not what I'm asking about.

Comment: Use the `I` function when you want a list to be a single column: `data.frame(items=I(items),results=vapply(items,eval,1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nicola's suggestion in the comment almost works, but doesn't display properly:

```
> data.frame(items=I(items),results=vapply(items,eval,1))
    items results
1 ^, 2, 1       2
2 ^, 2, 2       4
3 ^, 2, 3       8
4 ^, 2, 3       8
```

If you don't care about the display, I'd use that.  If you want it to display nicely, you need to convert the language objects to expression objects, e.g.

```
eitems <- lapply(items, as.expression)
> data.frame(items=I(eitems),results=vapply(items,eval,1))
  items results
1   2^1       2
2   2^2       4
3   2^3       8
4   2^3       8
```

or just deparse them to character values if you don't want to be able to evaluate them again:

```
ditems <- sapply(items, deparse)
> data.frame(items = ditems, results=vapply(items,eval,1))
  items results
1   2^1       2
2   2^2       4
3   2^3       8
4   2^3       8
```

Comment: Do you have an idea where this usage of `I()` is documented? Nowhere appears obvious to me, even the documentation for `I()` itself.

Comment: @J.Mini Both `?I` and `?data.frame` (details section) discuss the usage of `I`.

Comment: The `deparse` solution seems so much simpler than the `as.expression` solution that I'm unsure why you mentioned `as.expression`. For these cases, is there ever a reason to not use `deparse` instead?

Comment: `deparse()` is not guaranteed to succeed.  There are some weird R objects that it can't handle.  I'd guess it can handle anything that `alist()` would produce, but I might be wrong.  It's also quite commonly true that evaluating an expression will give a different value than deparsing it, parsing it, and evaluating.  The most common cause of this is rounding during deparsing, e.g. 1.000000000000001 deparses as 1, but internally it's not equal to 1.